# Changing format of time series in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to generate data series :-

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import numpy as np
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import cycle, islice
month_input = "Jan"
year_input  = 2018
month_start= str(month_input)
year_start = int(year_input)
start = pd.to_datetime(f'{month_start}{year_start}', format='%b%Y')
end = pd.to_datetime(f'{month_input}{year_start + 1}', format='%b%Y') - pd.Timedelta('1d') # Generating Date Range for an Year
daily_series_cal = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start, end)})
```

When I am trying to do:

```
print(daily_series_cal["Date"][0])
```

It is giving as output as :-

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

How can I change the format of whole column to `01/01/2018` ie `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html), but lost datetimes and get strings:

```
daily_series_cal = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start, end).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')})
```